# Let $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{N}$ and $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be smooth. Then $f$ is continuous w.r.t. the subspace topology $\tau_X$ of $X$

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, differential-topology

I'm reading a lecture [note](https://minterscompactness.files.wordpress.com/2019/01/Differential_Geometry_Part_II_Notes.pdf) about *Definition 1.8* of derivative of a function between smooth manifolds. There is a subtle problem of how the map $h$ in that definition is well-defined, leading me to below result. Could you verify if my understanding is correct?

---

First, I recall related definitions from the note to avoid ambiguity.

- Let $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{N}$ be **open**. A map $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is **smooth** if all  of its partial derivatives of all orders exist and are continuous.
- Let $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{N}$, $Y \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$, $f: X \rightarrow Y$, and $x \in X$. A map $\tilde{f}: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a **smooth extension** of $f$ around $x$ if $U$ is open in $\mathbb R^N$, $x \in U$, $\tilde f$ is smooth, and $\tilde{f}$ agrees with $f$ on $U \cap X$.
- Let $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{N}$ and $Y \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$. A map $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is **smooth** if $f$ has a smooth extension around any $x \in X$.

**Theorem:** Let $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{N}$, $Y \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$, and $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be smooth. Then $f$ is continuous w.r.t. the subspace topology $\tau_X$ of $X$.

---

**Proof:** Fix $x \in X$ and let $\tilde f:U \to \mathbb R^n$ be a smooth extension of $f$ around $x$. Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $X$ such that $x_n \xrightarrow{\tau_X} x$.

Let $d$ be the usual Euclidean metric on $\mathbb R^N$. Then $\tau_X$ is the same as the topology induced by $d_X :=d_{\restriction X \times X}$. It follows that $x_n \xrightarrow{d_X} x$ and thus wlog we can assume $x_n \in U$ for all $n$. This means $x_n \in U \cap X$ for all $n$. It follows that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \tilde f(x_n)$. On the other hand, $\tilde f$ is differentiable and thus  $\lim_{n \to \infty} \tilde f(x_n) = \tilde f(x)$. Finally, $$\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = \tilde f(x) = f(x).$$

So $f$ is continuous w.r.t. $\tau_X$. As a direct consequence, if $O$ is open in $\mathbb R^n$ or open in $Y$, then $f^{-1}(O)$ is open in $X$.

Comment: Looks good to me............